# Problema ao persistir no SPRING-DATA/JPA usando Chave composta / Não retorna Id gerado

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data

Olá alguém já teve esse problema, quando salva uma classe com chave composta, a API do Spring Data não retorna com o id gerado?

Fiz um teste com classes primitivas com id único então funciona normalmente e retorna o id gerado.

Segue as classes

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SMSEnviado")
public class SMSEnviado implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @EmbeddedId
    protected SMSEnviadoPK sMSEnviadoPK;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "mensagem")
    private String mensagem;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "dataEnvio")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date dataEnvio;  

    // gets and sets()...


}
```

```
@Embeddable
public class SMSEnviadoPK implements Serializable {

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "idSMSEnviado")
    private int idSMSEnviado;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "semana")
    private short semana;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "ano")
    private short ano;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "codigoRevenda")
    private String codigoRevenda;

    // gets and sets()...

}
```

[image: idSMSEnviado = null]

Uso o `SMSEnviadoPK` assim:

```
SMSEnviadoPK smsEnvioPk = new SMSEnviadoPK();
smsEnvioPk.setAno((short)ano);
smsEnvioPk.setCodigoRevenda(revenda.getCodigorevenda());
smsEnvioPk.setSemana((short)semana);
SMSEnviado smsEnviado = new SMSEnviado(smsEnvioPk);
smsEnviado.setDataEnvio(new Date());
smsEnviado.setMensagem(sms.getMensagem());
smsEnviado = enviadoImpl.save(smsEnviado);
```

Comment: Onde e como você chama os setters do `SMSEnviadoPK`?

Comment: Resolvido.. pois tinha que fechar o commit do JPA.